# Mongo DB, Python : Upsert for every 10000 records.

Tags: python, mongodb

I have to upsert the records in the MongoDB. I used a simple logic but it didn't work. Kindly help me fix this.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
import sys
import os
client = MongoClient('localhost', 9000)
db1 = client['Com_Crawl']
collection1 = db1['All']
posts1 = collection1.posts
ll=[]
f=file(sys.argv[1],'r')
for i in f:
    j=json.loads(i)
    ll.append(j)
#print ll
print len(ll)
count = 0
for l in ll:
    count = count+1
    if count <= 10000:
        print count,l
        print posts1.update({'vtid':l},{'$set': {'processed': 0}},upsert = True,multi = True)
print "**** Success ***"
```

The file contains 10 million records. The above code has inserted a new column and updated its value to '0' for 10000 records. But how can the rest of records in a batch of 10000 per execution.

Comment: Not sure about the batching part, but this loop only upserts while `count <= 10000` and count is never reset.  So once you hit 10000 records, the upsert doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: Yeah.. but how can I reset the count for the next set of values.

Comment: You probably just want to increment in steps of 10000 and insert a slice of `ll` at each step.  Use `range` Instead of iterating through each element.

Comment: Oh. You mean I have to change the loop and the count value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb has bulk update operations which will update the database in bulk. you can add any no of dict and can update in a single go but it internally updates 1000 by 1000 in batch [refer this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html) to get an idea about ordered and unordered bulk operation and [refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) to get an idea about bulk update [refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk/) to know how bulk operations work. So if you follow bulk update it wiil be

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 9000)
db1 = client['Com_Crawl']
collection1 = db1['All']
posts1 = collection1.posts
bulk = collection1.posts.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
ll=[]
f=file(sys.argv[1],'r')
for i in f:
    j=json.loads(i)
    ll.append(j)
#print ll
print len(ll)
count = 0
for index,l in enumerate(ll):
   bulk.find({'vtid':l}).update({'$set': {'processed': 0}},upsert = True,multi = True)
    if (index+1)%10000 == 0:
        bulk.execute() #this updates the records and prints the status.
        bulk = collection1.posts.initialize_unordered_bulk_op() #reinitialise for next set of operations.
bulk.execute() #this updates the remaining last records.
```

as pointed by **Joe D** you can also skip the records and update in bulk.

Comment: Thanks Mani. But I come across AttributeError: 'BulkOperationBuilder' object has no attribute 'update'.

Comment: Oh okay. Let me try now. I have a doubt; Now does update() needs upsert option ? because when I used find in the query, `bulk.find({'vtid':l}).update({'$set': {'processed': 0}},upsert = True,multi = True)
TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upset'`

Comment: when you set `upsert=True` it will create new record if the match is not found. if `upsert` is set to `false` it 'll not do anything if match is not found. Also note that in the comment posted I see it is mentioned as `'upset'` in the error. please check that.

Comment: I thought upsert will make a difference. Sorry for confusing. TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upsert' I still receive an error like the above.

Comment: Can you please check your pymongo version?

Comment: I'm new to Mongodb. sorry for too many questions. I'm using pymongo 3.4.0.

Comment: your version supports `upsert` in different way like this `bulk.find().upsert().update()` [refer this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#ordered-bulk-write-operations) for details.

Comment: so `upsert=True` should be specified in your version as `bulk.find().upsert().update()` where as `upsert=False` 'll be specified as `bulk.find().update()` which means by default `upsert` is `False`

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this instead.

```
for l in ll:
    for post in posts1.find({}).skip(count*10000).limit(10000):
        print post.update({'vtid':l},{'$set': {'processed': 0}},upsert = True,multi = True)
    count += 1
print "**** Success ***"
```

`skip()` does exactly what you'd think, it skips that many entries in the queryset, then `limit()` limits that results to 10000. So essentially you're using `count` to get the entries starting with 0, 10000, 20000, etc. and limit only grabs 10000 after that starting point.

Comment: Thank you Joe D. I shall try now.

Comment: TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'skip' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists. I come across this error. @Joe D

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see that it was a collection, I'll update it. @NiviSra

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks @JoeD

Comment: I'm updating only one value but I find an error. "TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2"